# Как правильно вызвать метод в интерфейсе

Tags: java, интерфейс

Есть метод, который редактирует заявку.

```
/**
 * Редактирование заявок.
 *
 * @param fresh новая заявка.
 */
public void update(Item fresh) {
    for (int index = 0; index != items.length; ++index) {
        if (items[index].getId().equals(fresh.getId())) {
            items[index] = fresh;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

В интерфейсе редактирование заявки вынесено в отдельный метод.

```
private void changeItem() {
    System.out.println("------------ Изменения заявки --------------");
    String newname = this.input.ask("Введите имя заявки :");
    String newdesc = this.input.ask("Введите описание заявки :");
    Item newItem = new Item(newname, newdesc, System.currentTimeMillis());
    newItem.setId(tracker.getAll()[0].getId());
    this.tracker.update(newItem);
}
```

Здесь редактируется только первая заявка. Как обратится к заявке по имени и именно ее отредактировать?

***Структура класса Item, как и просили***.

```
public class Item implements Cloneable {

    /**
     * Поле имя.
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * Поле описание.
     */
    private String description;

    /**
     * Поле создание.
     */
    private Long create;

    /**
     * Поле id.
     */
    private String id;

    /**
     * Конструктор класса Item.
     *
     * @param name        имя.
     * @param description описание.
     * @param create      создание.
     */
    public Item(String name, String description, Long create) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.create = create;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "name = " + name + "\n" + "description = " + description;
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * GetName.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * SetName.
     *
     * @param name имя.
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * GetDescription.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * SetDescription.
     *
     * @param description описание.
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * GetCreate.
     *
     * @return Long
     */
    public Long getCreate() {
        return create;
    }

    /**
     * SetCreate.
     *
     * @param create создание.
     */
    public void setCreate(Long create) {
        this.create = create;
    }

    /**
     * GetId.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * SetId.
     *
     * @param id id.
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

***Класс Трекер***

```
public class Tracker {
    /**
     * Поле массив item.
     */
    private Item[] items = new Item[100];

    /**
     * Поле позиция заявок.
     */
    private int position = 0;

    /**
     * Поле генерация id.
     */
    private static final Random RN = new Random();

    /**
     * Добавление заявок.
     *
     * @param item массив.
     * @return Item
     */
    public Item add(Item item) {
        item.setId(this.generateId());
        this.items[position++] = item;
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Редактирование заявок.
     *
     * @param fresh новая заявка.
     */
    public void update(Item fresh) {
        for (int index = 0; index != items.length; ++index) {
            if (items[index].getId().equals(fresh.getId())) {
                items[index] = fresh;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Удаление заявок.
     *
     * @param id заявки.
     */
    public void delete(String id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] != null && items[i].getId().equals(id)) {
                items[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получение списка всех заяво.
     *
     * @return Item[]
     */
    public Item[] getAll() {
        Item[] result = new Item[this.position];
        for (int index = 0; index != this.position; index++) {
            result[index] = this.items[index];
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Получение списка по имени.
     *
     * @param key ключевое слово для поиска
     * @return Item[].
     */
    public Item[] findByName(String key) {
        Item[] result = new Item[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] != null && items[i].getName().equals(key)) {
                Item[] temp = new Item[result.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(result, 0, temp, 0, result.length);
                temp[temp.length - 1] = items[i];
                result = temp;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Получение заявки по id.
     *
     * @param id заявки.
     * @return Item
     */
    public Item findById(String id) {
        Item result = null;
        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item != null && item.getId().equals(id)) {
                result = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Генерация id.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String generateId() {
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + RN.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: структуру класса Item надо бы

Comment: Добавил Item, если будет полезен. Есть также методы поиска заявки по имени и по id.

Comment: "Как обратится к заявке по имени и именно ее отредактировать?" - где у вас хранятся заявки?

Comment: Заявки хранятся в массиве. Да, именно по имени, можно по имени и описании тоже

Comment: Можно всё то же самое, только вместо `getId()` сравнивать `getName()`

Comment: Меняется именно первая заявка, а я хочу, чтобы я набрал по имени именно ту заявку, которая мне нужна и изменить ее. То есть по сути, я должен ввести имя и описание, программа должна найти эту заявку. Потом я должен ввести новые данные и они должны встать вместо первых.

Comment: так идите по хранилищу заявок и проверяйте, если найдете подходящую - меняйте

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Я получаю его id в строке newItem.setId(tracker.getAll()[0].getId());

Comment: выложите полностью класс где у пытаетесь редактировать запись + объясните как организовали хранение.

Comment: Выложил класс со всеми своими методами

Comment: Класс Item является хранилищем заявок

Comment: Cэкономлю ваше время. Метод changeItem должен вызвать метод update. Метод update выполняет свою функцию правильно. Нужно ввести с клавиатуры имя и описание(q и w соответственно) и заменить их на e и r. Дело в том, что метод  changeItem меняет только 0 элемент в массиве, то есть первую заявку. Мне надо ввести с клавы название и описание любой заявки и потом именно ее и отредактировать. Я не знаю, как это реализовать (незнание синтаксиса)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Переопределите метод equals в классе Item, чтобы можно было сравнивать записи. Тут сами решите нужно учитывать дату создания записи или нет. Если надо, то напишите дополнительный метод, который будет сравнить Item по названию и описанию

---

```
boolean equalsNameDescription(Item item){
   return this.name.equals(item.name) && 
          this.description.equals(item.description)
}
```

---

2. В классе Tracker напишите метод, который пройдет по массиву и найдет запись по имени и описанию.

---

```
int getIdByItem(Item findItem){
    for(Item item : items){
        if(item != null && item.equalsNameDescription(findItem))
            return item.getId();
        }

    return -1;
}
```

---

3. Описанный вами проблемный метод теперь можно переписать так:

---

```
private void changeItem() {
        System.out.println("------------ Изменения заявки --------------");
        String newname = this.input.ask("Введите имя заявки :");
        String newdesc = this.input.ask("Введите описание заявки :");
        Item newItem = new Item(newname, newdesc, System.currentTimeMillis());
        int id = tracker.getIdByItem(newItem);
        if(id == -1){
            // здесь напишите, что делать если такой запиcи нет
            throw new NotFoundException();  
        }
        newItem.setId(id);
        this.tracker.update(newItem);
    }
```

---

Из советов:

Смените массив на `ArrayList<Item>` разницы не почувствуете, но избавитесь от пары лишних строк. Либо на `Map<Iteger, Item>`. тогда сможете доставать записи по id

Comment: Спасибо большое